# Laravel auth gurad check is not working in constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

Having the below code in constructor,

```
public function __construct(){
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()){
        dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name);
    }
}
```

This is not working.

But this is working in other controller functions.

Comment: I assume you're calling this in a `Controller` constructor?

Comment: @devk, yes it is Controller constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.3 you are no longer able to access session (and thus `Auth` stuff as well) in controller constructors, [because session middleware has not run yet](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-session-in-constructor).

[5.3 changes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade) - scroll to "Session In The Constructor" to see how to get around it.